# Imagemagick convert massively increasing filesize?

Tags: image, png, imagemagick

I want to resize some PNG images with imagemagick, but it's making the files 5 times larger when I convert them:

```
$ convert -resize 50% -quality 80 01.png 01_half.png
$ ls -hal 01*.*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 3.3M Sep  9 09:05 01_half.png
-rwxr-xr-x 1 651K Jan 13  2011 01.png
```

From 651KB to 3.3MB! Can anyone suggest how to stop this happening?

Comment: Just noticed that this is a possible duplicate of the (unanswered) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492056/imagemagick-png-resize-increases-file-size

Comment: Not really a programming question - try http://superuser.com ?

Comment: am using imagemagick 6.2.8, incidentally.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that ImageMagick's `quality` option's behavior is different with PNG's than it is with eg JPG's, and 80 looks like a pretty odd value for PNG's.  As explained in the [manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/command-line-options.html#quality) quality's value is cut in 2 where the first digit controls the zlib compression factor, and the second digit controls the filter type.

Comment: Just tried without the `-quality` option, and it resizes it to 3.7MB.

Comment: @richard weird... check http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#png_quality for extra info regarding png compression.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Am trying `quality 02` etc but not getting anywhere. Maybe I need OptiPNG.

Comment: @richard fixing the first digit to 9 (for max. compression) won't hurt I think.  But you may be right.

Comment: I ended up doing batch process in IrfanView on a Windows machine :-/